# How to Create Data Markers on a MatLab Plot That Have Lines Extending to X/Y Axis?

Tags: matlab, plot, matlab-figure

I am attempting to create a plot in MatLab of a specified function which has specific data markers that have drop down lines (preferably dashed) to the X/Y axis the correspond to that specific marker.

Below is my MatLab code for just the plot and the markers:

```
x = 0:4000;
y = 1 - exp(-(power(((x-900)/1015.54),2)));
xmarkers = [1800,2000];
ymarkers = 1 - exp(-(power(((xmarkers-900)/1015.54),2)));

plot(x,y,'b',xmarkers,ymarkers,'b*');
```

This results in the following plot:

[image: MatLabPlotJustMarkers]

I envision a graph like this, preferably with automatic labels for the specified X/Y value pair at the end of the lines:

[image: EnvisionedMatLabPlot]

My core question would be: Is this possible? And if it is, how would one go about coding this? I understand I could probably manage this manually by adding lines to the plots myself, but this is infeasible for large amounts of markers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can define a function which draws the marker:

```
function draw_marker(x, y)

    hold on

    plot(x, y, 'b*')

    % plot coordinates as text
    str = sprintf('(%d, %d)', x, y);
    text(x, y, str)

    plot([0, x], [y, y], 'k-.')
    plot([x, x], [0, y], 'k-.')

end
```

And then you can create your plot like this:

```
plot(x,y,'b');

draw_marker(xmarkers(1), ymarkers(1))
draw_marker(xmarkers(2), ymarkers(2))
```

It would be nicer, of course, if you hand the figure handles as an argument, but the above works.

Comment: That is wonderful. Thank you. Would you mind just explaining what exactly is going on in terms of the calls to plot in the function/? Also, an aside, is it possible to have it label the value of x/y at the end of each line?

Comment: `plot` just plots to the current figure. The `hold on` statement keeps old plots visible instead of replacing them with each new `plot` call.

Comment: @AndrewC I'm not sure how easy it is to add tick labels on top of the existing tick labels, but I edited my answer to label the markers in the plot, I hope that's fine too!